# Mashed and gravy? Delicious!

Tags: riddle

> I am a man whose need is dier
>   My work is kinda shady
>   Or it is a roaring fire
>   It's all either mashed or gravy

Who am I?

Comment: Do you mean dire instead of dier?

Comment: No, I did not..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Mortician

I am a man whose need is dier

> They need people to die for work in order to make money

My work is kinda shady

> Working with dead bodies is kinda shady

Or it is a roaring fire

> Cremation

It's all either mashed or gravy

> Not sure here

Comment: I'm willing to confirm that this is correct, but I can't give you the check without the last clue ;-) I can say there are *two* different clues in that, and that it has nothing to do with food.

Comment: gravy=grave+-y?

Comment: mashed  = m + ash + ed?

Comment: mashed = M*A*S*H (mobile something somthing hospital)?

Comment: @f" has the gravy part (I mean what is more gravy (grave-like) than a grave!) and if it doesn't go into a grave, what happens?

Comment: I think @APrough figured out the 'mASHed' clue

Comment: I'm giving max the check, but the mash is because, Morbid Fact Of The Day: urns of ashes aren't ashes, they're made of bones. When you're cremated, any fleshy material is completely incinerated and only the bones survive. These bones are ground (mashed) into a fine powder and placed in an urn. This is why they ask you not to spread ashes because you're spreading dangerous bone pieces that can hurt animals.

Answer (score -3):

Is it

> the guy who works at a Cemetery

Because :

> he needs people to die to stay in business
>  he could either burn bodies(fire reference) or be burying them( mashed and Gravy)

Comment: he needs people to die to stay in business, he could either burn bodies(fire reference) or be burying them( mashed and Gravy)

Comment: This is the same as Maxqueue's answer. Also, please put your explanation in the answer, not in a comment.